# parsing variables from a Linux terminal in an R script

Tags: raster, r, linux

So I wanted to parse a variable with raster data to an R script. Now I found something like this (https://www.reddit.com/r/Rlanguage/comments/6p8a8q/r_shell_script/) but I don't really think it's gonna work.

Comment: Could you explain more about what you are trying to do without a link to Reddit?

Comment: @Spacedman Why yes. I wanted to bring a string with it's value inside my Rscript. You see, I'm working with Shell scripts and I wanted to input a raster image in a variable and then see if I can input that raster inside my R script so I can then output a few results from my analysis, like a data summary, or even a min-max.

Comment: You can pass command line args to R and get them via the `commandArgs()` function, or you could pass via environment variables and get them via `Sys,getenv()`. Is that the sort of thing?

Comment: Yes but I didn't know if there was a way to export results from Rscript back to shellscript, because I wanted to test GRASS GIS commands in the same script using rasters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

tiff=$1
echo $tiff

Rscript foo.R "$tiff"
```

And a corresponding `foo.R` file:

```
library(raster)
r = raster(commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)[1])
print(r)
```

Then you can run the bash script with a file argument, that gets passed into R, and you can read the file into a raster and print the info:

```
$ ./foo.sh aegiss.tiff
aegiss.tiff
Loading required package: methods
Loading required package: sp
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 480, 480, 230400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 480, 0, 480  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : /nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/aegiss.tiff 
names       : aegiss 
values      : 0, 255  (min, max)
```

See R documentation for more complex argument handling. This only works with one argument. There's also R packages for handling standard `--foo=bar` style argument parsers if it gets more than trivial.

Comment: Yes, that. Now the only thing I have to test was to export a ndvi raster and then find a way to pass that to GRASS using the same shell.